# Using an increment to access array Twilio Studio

Tags: javascript, for-loop, twilio, liquid, twilio-studio

I am working with two widgets for the purposes of this question:
The Set variables widget, and the split based on the widget. I want to iterate over my array which I am passing in (`flow.data.arr`):

I am trying in set variables:

```
key: increment
value: {% if flow.variables.increment %}{{flow.variables.increment | plus:1}}{% else %}0{% endif %}
```

and in the split based on:

```
condition: flow.data.arr[increment].nestedValue isNotBlank
```

I have tested with numbers and if I insert a 0 or 1 then it works perfectly. My assumption is that it is evaluating the `increment` var as a string, as when I had included spaces inside of the if logic, it added those spaces inside of the string.

SO If my assumption is correct, how can I make Twilio evaluate `increment` as a number? If my assumption is wrong how can I achieve this "for loop" style iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Twilio should be storing the variable as a number, Twilio will store it as a string. You have to do explicit casting before using the number to index the array.

In the split based on you can use:

```
condition:
{% assign i=flow.variables.increment | plus:0 %}
{{flow.data.arr[i].nestedValue}} isNotBlank
```

To achieve the desired result. Adding 0 will cast it to a number at the moment of use.